# Uncaught syntax error with jquery plugin and chrome, works fine in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome

Basically I'm trying to develop a simple plugin that allows us to dynamically generate our GA onclicks straight from JSON. So I developled this quick script. Works great but chrome fires "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Suggestions?

Test HTML file:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="modules/onclicks/onclickify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('modules/onclicks/clicks.json', function(data) {
        $('#analytics').onclickify(data);
    });
});

</script>
<script id="analytics"></script>
```

jQuery plugin file

```
(function( $ ){



$.fn.onclickify = function(clicks) {  

var onclicks = "";

return this.each(function() {

  $.each(clicks, function(key, value){

    onclicks += "$('"+value.selector+"')";
    onclicks += ".live('click', function(){\n";
    onclicks += "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent',";
    onclicks += value.name+"','";
    onclicks += value.label+"','";
    onclicks += value.action+"');\n";
    onclicks += "});\n\n";

  });

  $(this).append(onclicks);

});

};
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Do you have a line number with the error?

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to work. You can't append a blob of jQuery source code like that. Well, you can, but it's not going to do anything like what you think it is.

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but I *think* you could just do it like this:

```
(function( $ ){



$.fn.onclickify = function(clicks) {  

   return this.each(function() {

     $.each(clicks, function(key, value){

      $(value.selector)
        .live('click', function(){
         _gaq.push(['_trackEvent',
           value.name,
           value.label,
           value.action
         ]);
       });
     });
   });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Seems to be majority working, except it won't fire the network request to GA. Not sure why as the function is definitely attaching to the selectors.

Comment: When you build a string of code like that and append it to the DOM, at best what's going to happen is that the code will show up on the screen as plain text. It certainly will not be evaluated.